# How to specify an overlay image all four corners coordinates in php imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, coordinates, imagick

I am a beginner in Imagemagick / Imagick, so please bear with me. My issue looks rather simple, but I could not find a solution, or any help anywhere. Please take a look at the image below - I am trying to create an image, by specifying all four corners coordinates in pixels.

I looked at *Affine Distortion* but that function is too complicated for me, sometimes takes a while to be executed, and when it works - the results are very unpredictable (image rotation is wrong, there are parts of the image removed or misplaced, etc.) So if anyhow possible, I would not like to have to use Affine distortion.

Of course, if it is not possible to just specify each corner coordinates, a help in which direction I should be going is greatly appreciated. I would like to use Imagick, but if this is maybe better to do with GD or similar, I am open for that.

[image: 1]]

Comment: There is an example at http://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/screenEmbed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing source images, and what the expected result would be, I would assume you are attempting Perspective distortion. Meaning you want to take an image, and transform the MBR coordinates to a predefined set of points.

If I'm given a 400x400 checkerboard image, and want to distort it to the points listed above, the following ImageMagick command would work.

```
convert -size 400x400 pattern:checkerboard \
        -virtual-pixel transparent \
        -mattecolor transparent \
        -distort Perspective '0,0 50,153  400,0 240,40 0,400 315,355 400,400 336,156' \
        distorted_checkerboard.png
```

[image: distorted_checkerboard.png]

The `-distort Perspective '... point matrix ...'` reads as the following

```
  Origin Point  => Finial Point
    0,  0       =>  50,153       (top left)
  400,  0       => 240, 40       (top right)
    0,400       => 315,255       (bottom left)
  400,400       => 336,155       (bottom right)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried both Perspective and Bilinear distortion, but it looks like my mistake was in the different order of points. For bilinear, the order is TL, TR, BR, BL, but for Perspective it is TL, TR, BL, BR.

Comment: @johnny Happy to help. I believe the bilinear & perspective distortion matrix is independent of the given point order. As long as the SRC & DST points match, the distortion matrix will not be affected.